# Revogar privilégios

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho um *database* e estou tentando fazer com que apenas o meu usuário tenha acesso a essa base. ou seja ninguém mais poderá abrir, pesquisar, deletar nada. Estou usando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
GRANT USAGE ON batabase.* TO 'fabricio'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Mas não mudou nada todos os usuários continuam podendo fazer qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para revogar privilégios você precisa usar o [`REVOKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html). `GRANT` serve apenas para dar privilégios. O fato de você dar privilégios para um usuário não revoga automaticamente o privilégio de ninguém. Desta forma:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM usuario1, usuario2
```

Você pode listar todos os usuários separados por vírgula. Acho que o padrão de nomes de usuário você sabe: `'outrousuario'@'%'`

Para um banco de dados específico:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON banco.* FROM usuario1, usuario2
```

Lembrando que você só precisa retirar privilégios de usuários que os têm. Se eles nunca receberam privilégios eles já não conseguem acesso.

Obviamente você precisa ter privilégio para fazer isto.

Para confirmar os privilégios configurados para cada usuário use:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR usuario
```

Para listar os privilégios de todos os usuários:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR '%'@'%'
```

ou

```
SELECT sql_grants FROM common_schema.sql_show_grants
```

Como informação adicional é possível simplificar a retirada de privilégios de todos os usuários:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON banco.* FROM '%'@'%'
```

Obviamente se precisa que um usuário específico ter o acesso deve dar os privilégios para ele:

```
GRANT USAGE ON banco.* TO 'usuario'@'%'
```

Após terminar todo o processo pode ser interessante usar `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` para garantir o novo estado imediatamente.

Óbvio que não é possível revogar privilégios que o usuário não tem naquele *host*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Other/Revoke.sql).

Comment: `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON BdAlunos.* FROM 'root'@'%'` basta colar isto no MySQL. Se você tiver outros usuários basta repetir o processo para cada um deles. Tem outras formas de fazer isto, em tese mais simples, mas acho que você vai se confundir.

Comment: deu o seguinte erro Error Code: 1141. There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host '%'

Comment: Provavelmente porque este usuário não tem privilégios neste banco de dados. Sugiro você ler o manual e entender todo o processo, todas as implicações. A resposta foi dada. Este *site* é suporte para utilização de softwares, ele é um *site* de perguntas e respostas objetivas. Como você está tendo dificuldades muito básicas para compreender cada passo do processo é nem é tão complicado, mas é mais do que você parece conseguir lidar, sugiro fortemente você contratar um profissional para fazer estas coisas para você. Você pode continuar perguntando aqui mas as perguntas precisam ter um foco.

Comment: Entendi bigown. Aparamente parece um duvida simples, traduzindo bem ao pé da letra o msg de erro está dizendo que o usuário root não tem permissão, mas, sim ele tem permissão global. A solução seria excluir o usuário root, mas, e se o cliente tiver um aplicação mysql rodando, aí vou ferrar dom BD dele.

Comment: só para piorar ainda o debate veja a sintax REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'root'@'localhost';
Esse deu certo ele aceita, mas eu não posso restringir, gostaria mesmo é que apenas o usuário fabricio tive acesso ao BdAlunos.

Comment: Não, a mensagem de erro dize que não há uma definição de privilégio para o usuário `root`, que não precisa retirar privilégio porque ele já não tem. Mande listar os privilégios como mostrei na resposta para ver todos os privilégios existentes. O erro não diz que a a operação foi negada. Ela só não pode ser realizada porque ela não faz sentido.